# Powershell: Monitor CPU and RAM percentage usage and send email alert

Tags: powershell, scripting

I need to do a monitor for cpu and ram usage but about percentage in Powershell.
I tried to do some things but it is weird.
The code has two parts and I need to combine these parts and be able to send an email.
My big problem is about email when it is not legible.

First part:

```
$repeat_count = 3
$cpu_threshold = 80
$sleep_interval = 5
$hit = 0
foreach($turn in 1..$repeat_count) {
$cpu = (gwmi -class Win32_Processor).LoadPercentage
#write-host “CPU is $cpu`%”
If($cpu -ge $cpu_threshold) {
$hit = $hit+1
}
start-sleep $sleep_interval
}

if($hit -eq 3) {
write-host “CPU is more then $cpu_threshold`%”

Send-MailMessage -From user01@fabrikam.com -To user02@fabrikam.com -Subject “CPU2 is more then $cpu_threshold`%” -Body “CPU is $cpu`%” -Encoding UTF8 -SmtpServer smtp@fabrikam.com

} else {
write-host “CPU is under the limit”
}
```

Second part:

```
Get-Counter -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue '\Process(*)\% Processor Time' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty countersamples| Select-Object -Property instancename, cookedvalue| ? {$_.instanceName -notmatch "^(idle|_total|system)$"} | Sort-Object -Property cookedvalue -Descending| Select-Object -First 5| ft InstanceName,@{L='CPU';E={($_.Cookedvalue/100/$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS).toString('P')}} -AutoSize
```

Can You help me how I can send an email with legible -body?
Thank You very much

Comment: Append `ConvertTo-Html` to get a legible email `body`.
Else you may look at `ConvertTo-HtmlTable` if you need to aggregate some results.

Comment: There's already Performance Monitor built-in, it can send email alerts. Why not use it?

Comment: Why not use SCOM for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```html
#create an html email body 
 $body = @"
    <html>
        <body style="font-family:calibri"> 
        <b>Create your fancy Html email template here</b>
            <b>$table</b>
                </body>
    </html>
"@     


#Run your get command to populate your table var with info and convert to HTML
$table = Get-Counter -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue '\Process(*)\% Processor Time' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty countersamples| Select-Object -Property instancename, cookedvalue| ? {$_.instanceName -notmatch "^(idle|_total|system)$"} | Sort-Object -Property cookedvalue -Descending| Select-Object -First 5| select-object InstanceName,@{L='CPU';E={($_.Cookedvalue/100/$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS).toString('P')}} | convertto-html -Fragment
#this will send your HTML email.  
Send-MailMessage -From user01@fabrikam.com -To user02@fabrikam.com -Subject “CPU2 is more then $cpu_threshold`%” -body $body -SmtpServer smtp@fabrikam.com
```

enter code here

Hope this is helpful to you and good luck.