# PowerShell CPU and RAM % logging wrong values win 11 local in comparrison to windows 2022

Tags: windows, powershell, cpu, ram, taskmanager

I have written this PowerShell script to log the current CPU and RAM usage, but it seems to get the date wrong on my Windows 11 local pc.

[Local Windows 11 Sample1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OigGY.png)

[Local Windows 11 Sample2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjDAG.png)

[Comparison Win 2022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJ0Uk.png)

My Code:

```
# Number of CPU Cores

$cpuCores = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors

# Sampling interval in seconds

$sampleInterval = 1

# File path

$logFilePath = "C:\Users\walde\Desktop\PerfLog\" + (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd") + ".txt"

# Capture total available RAM

$totalPhysicalMemory = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).TotalPhysicalMemory / 1MB

# First sample for CPU times and RAM usage, as well as process names

$firstSample = @{}
$processRAMUsage = @{}
$processNames = @{}

Get-Process | ForEach-Object {
    $firstSample[$_.Id] = $_.TotalProcessorTime.TotalSeconds
    $processRAMUsage[$_.Id] = [math]::Round(($_.WorkingSet64 / 1MB) / $totalPhysicalMemory * 100, 2)
    $processNames[$_.Id] = $_.Name
}

# Wait for the next CPU sample

Start-Sleep -Seconds $sampleInterval

# Second sample for CPU times

$secondSample = @{}
Get-Process | ForEach-Object { $secondSample[$_.Id] = $_.TotalProcessorTime.TotalSeconds }

# Calculation of CPU usage and adding a timestamp

$timestamp = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

$cpuUsage = foreach ($id in $firstSample.Keys) {
    $secondCPU = $secondSample[$id]
    if ($secondCPU) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Timestamp = $timestamp
            ProcessName = $processNames[$id]
            CPUUsage = [math]::Round((($secondCPU - $firstSample[$id]) / $sampleInterval / $cpuCores) * 100, 2)
        }
    }
}

# CPU Log

$totalCPUUsage = [math]::Round(($cpuUsage | Measure-Object CPUUsage -Sum).Sum, 2)
$idleCPU = [math]::Round(100 - $totalCPUUsage, 2)

$totalAndIdleCPU = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{Timestamp = $timestamp; ProcessName = "Total CPU Usage"; CPUUsage = $totalCPUUsage},
    [PSCustomObject]@{Timestamp = $timestamp; ProcessName = "Idle CPU"; CPUUsage = $idleCPU}
)

$finalCPULogData = $totalAndIdleCPU + ($cpuUsage | Sort-Object CPUUsage -Descending)
$finalCPULogData | Select-Object -First 12 | Format-Table -AutoSize #| Out-String | Out-File -FilePath ($logFilePath) -Append

# RAM Log

$totalRAMUsage = [math]::Round(($processRAMUsage.Values | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum, 2)
$idleRAM = [math]::Round(100 - $totalRAMUsage, 2)

$ramUsage = foreach ($id in $processRAMUsage.Keys) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Timestamp = $timestamp
        ProcessName = $processNames[$id]
        RAMUsage = $processRAMUsage[$id]
    }
}

$totalAndIdleRAM = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{Timestamp = $timestamp; ProcessName = "Total RAM Usage"; RAMUsage = $totalRAMUsage},
    [PSCustomObject]@{Timestamp = $timestamp; ProcessName = "Idle RAM"; RAMUsage = $idleRAM}
)

$finalRAMLogData = $totalAndIdleRAM + ($ramUsage | Sort-Object RAMUsage -Descending)
$finalRAMLogData | Select-Object -First 12 | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String #| Out-File -FilePath ($logFilePath) -Append
```

Tried some other measuring scripts:
[Powershell: Monitor CPU and RAM percentage usage and send email alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70020396/powershell-monitor-cpu-and-ram-percentage-usage-and-send-email-alert)
But it also gets the Total CPU wrong.

Comment: The differences are running Task Manager as a regular user vs an Admin.  Normally Task Manager only show the current User and System usage (not other users).  Try running your PS script by right click the PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference on Windows 11 with or without admin.